# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> will crash hosted mode

Tags: gwt

Has anyone tried adding

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

to the app page html?

I would like use the better css implementation of IE9 (e.g. round corner) and added that piece of meta tag.  It will restart the IE every time i run hosted mode.  I have both gwt sdk 2.0.3 and  2.1 rc1 installed in different instance of eclipse and none of that work.

Comment: We probably have to wait until IE9 is formally supported by GWT. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5125

Comment: That's really bad.  GWT looks extremely ugly with IE8 default!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 is not officially supported yet, see [#5125](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5125&q=ie9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the comment above :)